# Limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{m=2^k}^{m=2^{k+1}} {\frac{2m}{2m-1}}$

Tags: limits, products

Does $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{m=2^k}^{m=2^{k+1}} {\frac{2m}{2m-1}}$$ exist?
[Wolfram alpha gives numbers around 1.4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%20%282k%29%2F%282k-1%29%20from%20k%3D512%20to%201024)

Comment: I think it converges to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AlexSilva. You are right : it is exactly $\sqrt 2$ using Pochhammer functions and going to limit.

Answer (score 2):

Define $$
\begin{align*}
p_k&=\prod_{m=2^k}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{2m}{2m-1}\\
\log p_k&=\sum_{2^k}^{2^{k+1}}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2m-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{2^k}^{2^{k+1}}\left[\frac{1}{2m-1}+\frac{O(1)}{(2m-1)^2}\right]\\
&=\int_{2^k}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{2x}\ dx+O(2^{-k})\\
&=\frac{\log (2^{k+1})-\log(2^k)}{2}+O(2^{-k})\\
&=\frac{\log 2}{2}+O(2^{-k}).
\end{align*}$$
Consequently the limit as $k\to\infty$ exists and equals $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I don't understand the changing from sum to integral. Could you explain?

Comment: Changing from a sum to an integral incurs a smaller order correction absorbed in the $O(2^{-k})$. It is just a Riemann sum for the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$A_k=\prod_{m=2^k}^{m=2^{k+1}}\frac{2m}{2m-1}\\
B_k=\prod_{m=2^k}^{m=2^{k+1}-1}\frac{2m+1}{2m}\\
A_kB_k=2^{k+2}/(2^{k+1}-1)\\
\frac{2^{k+2}+1}{2^{k+2}}B_k<A_k<\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}-2}B_k$$
 $A_k/B_k\to1$, and $A_kB_k\to2$
$\lim_{k\to\infty}A_k^2=\lim_{k\to\infty}(A_k/B_k)\lim_{k\to\infty}A_kB_k=1\times2$

Comment: it's a good proof, but it doesn't prove that the limit exists. you've only proved that if the limit exists, then it is equals to $\sqrt{2}$